# why the distance is different using Cartesian coordinates than latitude and longitude?

Tags: gis, distance, latitude-longitude

I have a latitude and longitude of some point I used the following function to fin distance between points. Then I used the next function to convert latitude and longitude to cartesian coordinates. when I use the following formula to find distance of point with cartesian coordinates, the result is different than the first method. why?

```
                                 (x^2+y^2+z^2)^0.5


def distance(lat2,lat1,lon2,lon1):
    distance=[]
    speed=[]
    accelerate=[]

        radius = 6371 # km

        dlat = math.radians(lat2-lat1)
        dlon = math.radians(lon2-lon1)
        a = math.sin(dlat/2) * math.sin(dlat/2) + math.cos(math.radians(lat1)) \
            * math.cos(math.radians(lat2)) * math.sin(dlon/2) * math.sin(dlon/2)
        c = 2 * math.atan2(math.sqrt(a), math.sqrt(1-a))
        d = radius * c
        distance.append(d)
    for i in range(len(distance)-1):
        speed.append((distance[i])/0.25)
    for i in range(len(speed)-1):
        accelerate.append((speed[i+1]-speed[i])/0.25)
    return distance,speed,accelerate


def X_Y_Z(latitude,longitude):
    R=6371
    X=[]
    Y=[]
    Z=[]

    for lat,lon in zip(latitude,longitude):
        x = R * math.cos(lat) * math.cos(lon)

        y = R * math.cos(lat) * math.sin(lon)

        z = R *math.sin(lat)
        X.append(x)
        Y.append(y)
        Z.append(z)
    return X,Y,Z
```

for example the distance between (40.714531     ,-73.725607) and (40.714527 ,   -73.725591) is 0.001377. But cartesian coordinates give me different distance:

(642.430295 ,   -6287.620268 ,  801.720448) and (642.527042     -6287.607109    801.746119)

Comment: because the earth is round

Comment: They should be nearly equal, but I do not understand your code and how do you calculate your results. For sure you didn't copied all code (missing `for` in the first function? And also how do you calculate the data, and what do you expect. In any case I also do not understand your method (the first way to calculate distances). You should add comments (and your speed is *strange*). Note: you use degree instead of radiants in the dlat/dlon part.